# How can I get both start and ending coordinates on Android Touch event (motion event)?

Tags: android, coordinates, touch-event

I have been asked to modify an existing code as part of an online course. Currently, the app registers and displays the x and y coordinates of the position where the screen is touched as well as the amount of time in milliseconds.

I want to add the function of getting both start and ending coordinates i.e. where the finger starts and where it ends while dragging. At the moment the registered coordinates seem to be only the ending ones. How can I add both sets of coordinates (e.g. if I want to calculate the distance of the motion event)? Here is part of the code. 
Thanks for your help!

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    Calendar tiempoInicio = null;
    Calendar tiempoFinal = null;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        int x = (int)event.getX();
        int y = (int)event.getY();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                tiempoInicio = Calendar.getInstance();
                break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                tiempoFinal = Calendar.getInstance();


                Intent intent = new Intent (
                                   AplicacionSencillaActivity.this,
                                AplicacionSencillaResults.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putLong(
                                "TIEMPOPRESIONADO",
                                tiempoFinal.getTimeInMillis() -
                                 tiempoInicio.getTimeInMillis());
                bundle.putInt("X", x);
                bundle.putInt("Y", y);

                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
```

Answer (score 0):

To get starting coordinates, you need to get and save `getX()` and `getY()` during the `ACTION_DOWN` event also, since that represents the start of the move.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your code is mostly right, `ACTION_DOWN` will give you the start, `ACTION_UP` - the end. Your mistake is overriding [`onTouchEvent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) - read the description, it says it will only be called if none of the views handled the touch, so your touch might be getting intercepted by some of your child views.

Override [`dispatchTouchEvent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) instead and you'll get all the touches. Don't forget to call `super.dispatchTouchEvent()` or you'll stop the touches from being delivered to views in your activity.

Comment: Thanks Ivan! However the app is still only registering the last coordinates. Do I need to getX and getY during ACTION_DOWN, as Geobits says below? If so, where exactly should I put the code?

Comment: Yes, I assumed that's what you already do :) The way it works is you receive all events the screen gives you and it's your job to figure out what's happening. I'd use a member to store state. Like `boolean mIsSwiping`. When you receive `ACTION_DOWN` set it to `true` and read your starting point coords. When you receive `ACTION_UP`: if `mIsSwiping` is `true` then read ending coords and set `mIsSwiping` to `false`, if not - nothing to do.

Comment: Check out this for reference: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.3_r1/android/widget/ScrollView.java#483 Note how for `ACTION_DOWN` they basically set `mIsBeingDragged` (depending on child count, but that's because it's `ScrollView`, you can't scroll unless it has a child) to `true` and for `ACTION_U`P or `ACTION_CANCEL` they set `mIsBeingDragged` to false